# Describe the Lie algebra of SL n (H) for H=Quaternion group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJHl3.jpg) (in the image there us an explaintion about SLn(H)
Describe the Lie algebra of SL_n(H) for H=Quaternion group, meaning H is the group of {1,i,j,k} that:
ij=k, 
jk=i, 
ki=j, 
ji=-k, 
kj=-i, 
ik=-j

Comment: What is $\textrm{SL}_n(\Bbb H)$?

Comment: It's not a full answer